# Как в оперативной памяти найти запущенную программу?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, взлом, системное-программирование

Предположим у нас есть пароль от `sudo`, который мы забыли. Хеш этого пароля записан в файле `/etc/shadow`, который можно открыть только при наличии `root` прав. Когда мы вводим в терминал `sudo su` - у нас запускается процесс `sudo su` и очевидно, что он к этому файлу доступ имеет. Процесс само собой, читает из файла необходимый хеш и сранвивает его с хешем того, что мы введем в ответ команде `sudo su`. Возможно ли в оперативной памяти найти память этого процесса `sudo su`(без root прав) , чтобы прочесть оттуда контекст, стек и кучу и отыскать хеш из `/etc/shadow`?

Если я что-то неврено понимаю в процессе работы ос и эвм, пожалуйста сообщите, я постарюсь разобраться и исправить вопрос!

Comment: Разные уровни доступа, запуская sudo su - вы не получаете доступа к его участку оперативной памяти, т.е. вы не можете прочесть кусок памяти в котором хранится хэш пароля. [Вотъ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кольца_защиты) немного вводной информации но не по линуксу, дальше по накатанной найдете и линуксовые системы

Comment: Чтобы шариться в памяти не своих процессов (а sudo - не ваш процесс, а рута), надо уже быть рутом. Кстати, почему sudo su, а не sudo bash?

Comment: Читайте [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (там для каждого процесса есть куча файлов, описывающих его ресурсы. Однако, для доступа к "чужим" вы должны быть root-ом)

Comment: @user_587 так короче, но почему не sudo -s или sudo -i ?)

Comment: @user_587, запускать `sudo bash` — это отвратительная практика. Попробуйте потом найти концы, если что-то пошло не так. На самом деле надо запускать каждую отдельную команду через `sudo` безо всяких там Shell оболочек. Тогда такие запуски подвержены аудиту.

Comment: @eri, почитайте мой комментарий выше.

Comment: нет смысла в аудите, если его никто не читает. @0andriy десктопную ос проще и быстрее переустановить чем восстанавливать.

Comment: @eri Если \то про *nix, то это в корне неверный подход.

Comment: @0andriy офтоп конечно но допустим. Юзер сделал случайно `sudo chown user:user /` ос работает, но теперь глючит.  Переустановить с сохранением хома - 20 минут. Восстановить... Ну полдня минимум

Comment: Раз уж в КСВ, то зачем вы такому пользователю рута выдали? :)

Comment: @0andriy "штатная" система получения рутовых прав, допускающая ситуацию "попробуйте потом найти концы" даже по случайности — это вообще так себе система безопасности. inb4: sudoers настроить умею, говорю про конфигурации по умолчанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вы не можете отыскать хеш из `/etc/shadow`

Comment: Ну, а если есть физический доступ  к компу, то ничто же не мешает загрузиться с флешки (получив root), подмонтировать диск с  /etc и прочесть там shadow

Comment: @avp, а чего не ответом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, слишком много инфы надо поднять, чтобы толково описать весь этот процесс (наизусть не помню, а экспериментировать лень)