# Способы получения root без пароля

Tags: python

Интересуюсь разработкой кода для получения root прав (линукс).
Пытался разными способами обойти запрос на введение пароля. (не получилось)
Почему интересуюсь таким?
Наткнулся на вирус который мне тупо снёс системные файлы.
Всё мы понимаем что без root прав, вирус не как до системных файлов не добрался бы.
Вот и стало интересно как так.
Было бы интересно рассмотреть ваши варианты, решение данной задачи.
Желательно на языке пайтон.

Comment: Ну так вы, скорее всего, запустили ваш "вирус" от рута

Comment: мне уже не мало лет, но фразу "роот прав" я вижу впервые.

Comment: Либо уязвимость, которую не успели ещё пофиксить, либо ещё что-то такое. "Легально" рутовские права не получится получить у скрипта.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1447826/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1447136/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83

Comment: смежные вопросы,направленные на похожее действие

Comment: Всегда работаю с второго аккаунта,

Answer (score 0):

Вирус как таковой не может просто обойти Root проверку(за исключением каких-нибудь уязвимостей ядра, про которые знают единицы)

Если на самом деле интересуешься, то советую больше акцентировать свою внимание на социальной инженéрии. Т.е. как заставить пользователя запустить файл от master-пользователя, если говорить грубо)

Comment: ну вот же товарищ пытается социально инженирить, чтобы ему вирус написали. вообще, не стоит давать такие "ответы" на подобные "вопросы".

Comment: Социальную инженерию направить на вирус: уговорить его взломать рута и передать права пользователю.

Comment: Благодарю, всегда пользовался вторым аккаунтом который роот прав не имел.

Comment: @GardenSpecial теперь еще отучитесь говорит "роот", и вас даже линуксоиды за своего примут.